# packer.io exit code of provisioning script

Tags: linux, virtualization, packer

I got packer.io for building VM images. I provision VMs with shell script which uses puppet.

Now sometimes there is situation where this provisioning script fails to provision VM correctly.

I am using Rundeck to trigger provisioning by packer.

I need a way how to tell Rundeck that provisioning script inside VM failed.

I haven't found anything in documentation of packer.io according this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to different handling of exit codes from puppet.

I had to use:

```
puppet apply --detailed-exitcodes /etc/puppet/modules/...
            if [[ $? != 2 ]]  
            then
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
```

This indicates to packer.io right exit code 1 when puppet not finishes with "everything went well" exit code 2.